# Perturbation of Laplacian

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, mathematical-physics

Let's consider a potential $V(x)\in L^3(\mathbb{R}^3)$. I want to know if the following Hamiltonian 
$$-\Delta+V(x)$$
is self-adjoint on $H^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$.
 My idea is to use Kato-Rellich theorem; so for $f\in D(-\Delta)=H^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ we have
$$\Vert Vf\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)}\leq\Vert V\Vert_{L^3(\mathbb{R}^3)}\Vert f\Vert_{L^6(\mathbb{R}^3)}$$
Now I can use Gagliardo-Niremberg-Sobolev inequality to get
$$\Vert f\Vert_{L^6(\mathbb{R}^3)}\leq C\Vert\Delta f\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)}^{\frac{1}{2}}\Vert f\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)}^{\frac{1}{2}}$$
Now I can use Young inequality
$$\Vert f\Vert_{L^6(\mathbb{R}^3)}\leq C(\epsilon\Vert\Delta f\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)}+\frac{1}{\epsilon}\Vert f\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)})$$
So we have that $V$ is bounded with respect to the Laplacian and so Kato-Rellich theorem gives the thesis.
Is there something worng in this reasoning?

Comment: It is a classical example in a textbook. Do you need it?